# Access denied for `systemd-inhibit --what=idle`

Tags: debian, systemd, polkit

#### Problem

On Debian 12 I use `IdleAction=poweroff` and `IdleActionSec=…` in `logind.conf`. This works as intended, the machine powers itself off when it's been idle for long enough.

I want to be able to use `systemd-inhibit --what=idle` as a regular user. I have found claims that it should be possible ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1621311/432690)). Indeed, in one of my Debian 12 systems it is possible, let's call this Debian *Successful*; but there are other Debian 12 systems where I get `Access denied`, let's call these *Failing*. The machine where I really need this functionality is in the *Failing* group.

It's not a temporary quirk (because of "needing to reboot" or something). I have just rebooted the *Successful* machine and one *Failing*, the behavior persists.

**Why the difference? What can I do to make a *Failing* system behave like the *Successful* one?**

I'm not really interested in workarounds like `sudo` or some custom wrapper. I'd like `systemd-inhibit --what=idle` to "just work", like it does on the *Successful* system. I'd like to adjust its behavior as much "by the systemd/polkit book" as possible.

---

#### Current behavior

This is how it works on the *Successful* system. This is what I want:

```
$ SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=7 systemd-inhibit --what=idle true
Bus n/a: changing state UNSET → OPENING
sd-bus: starting bus by connecting to /run/dbus/system_bus_socket...
Bus n/a: changing state OPENING → AUTHENTICATING
Bus n/a: changing state AUTHENTICATING → HELLO
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.75 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Bus n/a: changing state HELLO → RUNNING
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.login1 path=/org/freedesktop/login1 interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager member=Inhibit cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=ssss error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=:1.7 destination=:1.75 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=149 reply_cookie=2 signature=h error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Successfully forked off '(inhibit)' as PID 3384.
Skipping PR_SET_MM, as we don't have privileges.
true succeeded.
Bus n/a: changing state RUNNING → CLOSED
$ echo $?
0
$
```

This is how it fails on the *Failing* systems:

```
$ SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=7 systemd-inhibit true
Bus n/a: changing state UNSET → OPENING
sd-bus: starting bus by connecting to /run/dbus/system_bus_socket...
Bus n/a: changing state OPENING → AUTHENTICATING
Bus n/a: changing state AUTHENTICATING → HELLO
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.44 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Bus n/a: changing state HELLO → RUNNING
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.login1 path=/org/freedesktop/login1 interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager member=Inhibit cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=ssss error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=error sender=:1.1 destination=:1.44 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=464 reply_cookie=2 signature=s error-name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied error-message=Permission denied
Failed to inhibit: Access denied
Bus n/a: changing state RUNNING → CLOSED
$ echo $?
1
$
```

`true` is just an example. Ultimately I want to invoke some long-running command for which inhibiting makes perfect sense.

---

#### Details

- *Successful* and *Failing* are Debian 12.
- The kernel on *Successful* and on each *Failing* is `6.1.0-17-amd64`.
- The output of `id`:

  ```
  @Successful $ id
  uid=1000(kamil) gid=1000(kamil) groups=1000(kamil),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),100(users),106(netdev),111(bluetooth),113(lpadmin),117(scanner),124(pcspkr)
  ```

  ```
  @Failing1 $ id
  uid=1000(kamil) gid=1000(kamil) groups=1000(kamil),4(adm),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev)
  ```
- On each system `/usr/bin/systemd-inhibit` gives the same `md5sum`, I conclude the files are identical between *Successful* and *Failing*; they have not been tampered with. `ls -l /usr/bin/systemd-inhibit` prints:

  ```
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22928 11-10 01:25 /usr/bin/systemd-inhibit
  ```
- On each system `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf` gives the same `md5sum`, I conclude the files are identical between *Successful* and *Failing*; they have not been tampered with. The relevant(?) parts:

  ```
  <busconfig>

        <policy user="root">
                <allow own="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
        </policy>

        <policy context="default">
                <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
  [...]
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
                       send_member="Inhibit"/>
  [...]
                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
        </policy>

  </busconfig>
  ```
- On each system `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy` gives the same `md5sum`, I conclude the files are identical between *Successful* and *Failing*; they have not been tampered with. The relevant(?) parts:

  ```
  <policyconfig>
  [...]
        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.inhibit-block-idle">
                <description gettext-domain="systemd">Allow applications to inhibit automatic system suspend</description>
                <message gettext-domain="systemd">Authentication is required for an application to inhibit automatic system suspend.</message>
                <defaults>
                        <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
                        <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
                        <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
                </defaults>
        </action>
  [...]
  </policyconfig>
  ```

  I guess this `<allow_any>yes</allow_any>` is responsible for the alleged ability of a regular user to use `systemd-inhibit --what=idle`. Still on *Failing* systems it seems to be ignored.
- The *Successful* Debian uses its hardware directly. One *Failing* Debian is installed on HP ProLiant DL380 G5; other *Failing* Debians are virtual machines in VMware ESXi 7.
- I use `ssh` to connect to the *Successful* system and to each *Failing* one. The *Successful* system provides a GUI but it's "just in case"; currently `sddm` only sits there and I don't log in this way.
- The output of `pstree -lu`:

  ```
  @Successful $ pstree -lu
  systemd-+-ModemManager---2*[{ModemManager}]
          |-NetworkManager---2*[{NetworkManager}]
          |-accounts-daemon---2*[{accounts-daemon}]
          |-atop
          |-atopacctd
          |-avahi-daemon(avahi)---avahi-daemon
          |-blkmapd
          |-bluetoothd
          |-cron
          |-cups-browsed---2*[{cups-browsed}]
          |-cupsd
          |-dbus-daemon(messagebus)
          |-dhcpd
          |-exim4(Debian-exim)
          |-hostapd
          |-nfsdcld
          |-openvpn
          |-polkitd(polkitd)---2*[{polkitd}]
          |-rpc.idmapd
          |-rpc.mountd
          |-rpc.statd(statd)
          |-rpcbind(_rpc)
          |-rtkit-daemon(rtkit)---2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
          |-sddm-+-Xorg---10*[{Xorg}]
          |      |-sddm-helper---sddm-greeter(sddm)---11*[{sddm-greeter}]
          |      `-{sddm}
          |-smartd
          |-sshd-+-sshd---sshd(bisztynek)
          |      `-sshd---sshd(kamil)---bash---tmux: client
          |-systemd(sddm)-+-(sd-pam)
          |               |-dbus-daemon
          |               `-pulseaudio-+-gsettings-helpe---3*[{gsettings-helpe}]
          |                            `-2*[{pulseaudio}]
          |-systemd(kamil)-+-(sd-pam)
          |                |-dbus-daemon
          |                `-pulseaudio-+-gsettings-helpe---3*[{gsettings-helpe}]
          |                             `-{pulseaudio}
          |-systemd(bisztynek)-+-(sd-pam)
          |                    |-dbus-daemon
          |                    `-pulseaudio-+-gsettings-helpe---3*[{gsettings-helpe}]
          |                                 `-{pulseaudio}
          |-systemd-journal
          |-systemd-logind
          |-systemd-timesyn(systemd-timesync)---{systemd-timesyn}
          |-systemd-udevd
          |-tmux: server(kamil)---bash---pstree
          |-transmission-da(debian-transmission)---3*[{transmission-da}]
          |-udisksd---4*[{udisksd}]
          |-upowerd---2*[{upowerd}]
          `-wpa_supplicant
  ```

  ```
  @Failing1 $ pstree -lu
  systemd-+-VGAuthService
          |-agetty
          |-cron
          |-dbus-daemon(messagebus)
          |-dhclient
          |-nmbd
          |-rsyslogd---3*[{rsyslogd}]
          |-smbd-+-cleanupd
          |      |-smbd
          |      `-smbd-notifyd
          |-sshd---sshd---sshd(kamil)---bash---tmux: client
          |-systemd(kamil)---(sd-pam)
          |-systemd-journal
          |-systemd-logind
          |-systemd-timesyn(systemd-timesync)---{systemd-timesyn}
          |-systemd-udevd
          |-tmux: server(kamil)-+-2*[bash---nano]
          |                     `-bash---pstree
          `-vmtoolsd---2*[{vmtoolsd}]
  ```

  Other systems from the *Failing* group may run slightly different sets of tasks, they are all similarly minimalistic though.

---

#### Observation

One big difference between the *Successful* Debian and each *Failing* one is the GUI. There are `Xorg`, `sddm` and related processes on *Successful*. But as I said, I don't log in to the GUI at all. I don't know if it has anything do do with the problem. Maybe it's just a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the question, I noticed `polkitd` running in the *Successful* system, but not in any *Failing* one. I knew the problem has much to do with polkit, so I gave it a try in one Debian of the *Failing* group:

```
sudo apt-get install polkitd
```

And yes, this is it, problem solved. Now I can use `systemd-inhibit --what=idle` as a regular user.

I think on the *Successful* Debian `polkitd` was installed because of other packages (e.g. `network-manager`) that depend on it.

Originally the question was not supposed to be self-answered, I genuinely needed help. An example of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), I guess.